# Is there a Dell E7450 with i7?

Tags: dell-latitude

When I google and look at the speces then it says that the E7450 has an i5 CPU. But on my E7450 it says Intel i7. How can I know what I got? I bought it used but it is rather new computer. I suppose I can get the program CPU-Z to see what I got.

Comment: *"I suppose I can get the program CPU-Z to see what I got."* There you go.

Comment: You have confirmed you have an i7.  So what exactly is your question?  If you have a E7450 with an i7 then obviously there are E7450 with an i7.

Comment: I don't know - maybe I want to make sure that it is not a chinese Dell clone labelled i7 on the outside to raise the price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into **Control Panel** → **System** → and under **Processor** it will display what you have.

You can also use software such as CPU-Z or Speccy like you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

When I was buying my *super special* E7450 at my last place of employment, i7 was required to get nVIDIA graphics (840m, if I recall).  It's definitely an option.

I miss that laptop :\

DXDIAG will also report the CPU model, built-in to Windows.  More info is always available at http://ark.intel.com/